# Numpy matrix inversion with objects

Tags: python, numpy, galois-field, finite-field

I'm using the gf256 library to do galois field math, and I have it in a numpy matrix. Though when calling `np.linalg.inv()` with it, it throws an error.

That's the summary, here's the details:

```
import numpy as np
from gf256 import GF256 as gf
npgf = np.vectorize(gf)

arr = np.identity(4, np.uint8) * 10
gfarr = npgf(arr)
```

After all this, `gfarr` looks like this

```
array([[GF256(0b00001010), GF256(0b00000000), GF256(0b00000000),
        GF256(0b00000000)],
       [GF256(0b00000000), GF256(0b00001010), GF256(0b00000000),
        GF256(0b00000000)],
       [GF256(0b00000000), GF256(0b00000000), GF256(0b00001010),
        GF256(0b00000000)],
       [GF256(0b00000000), GF256(0b00000000), GF256(0b00000000),
        GF256(0b00001010)]], dtype=object)
```

And `np.linalg.inv(gfarr)` throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#152>", line 1, in <module>
    np.linalg.inv(gfarr)
  File "[python3.6]\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 528, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc inv
```

The matrix is definitely invertable, and the GF256 class supports all the usual operators. Is it possible to make this work with numpy?

Comment: `np.linalg.inv` uses compiled code, and as best I can tell expects the input `dtype` to be float (`double`) or something that can be cast to it (e.g. an int) (`complex` also works).  Object dtype does not work (even if the values are numbers).

Comment: If your library can implement the concept of a linear operator, with a matrix-vector product, you might be able to use the sparse linear algebra package: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html

Comment: As a general rule, `numpy.ufunc` work on a object dtype arrays by delegating the action to a method of the objects.  `add` delegates to `__add__`, `sin` to `.sin()` etc.  It iterates on the objects, much like a list comprehension would.  It does not perform fast compiled numpy calculations.

Answer (score 0):

`np.linalg.inv` will invoke a BLAS/LAPACK implementation of matrix inversion using floats, but you need to use Galois field arithmetic in the matrix inversion process. To do this, the NumPy array will need to intercept or override the call to `np.linalg.inv` in `__array_function__()`. The matrix inversion of `A` can be accomplished using Gaussian elimination on `[A | I]` over the Galois field, which yields `[I | A^-1]`.

I had a similar use case, so I created a Python package called [galois](https://github.com/mhostetter/galois) that extends NumPy arrays over Galois fields. It replaces the NumPy ufuncs with JIT compiled ufuncs using Numba. This means the array arithmetic is as fast, or nearly as fast, as normal NumPy arithmetic. See this [performance comparison](https://galois.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance/numpy-comparison.html).

It also supports linear algebra and overrides the relevant `np.linalg` functions. So the matrix inversion you're looking for works out of the box. Here's an example using your matrix.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                     

In [2]: import galois                                                                                                                                                                          

In [3]: GF = galois.GF(2**8)                                                                                                                                                                   

In [4]: print(GF.properties)                                                                                                                                                                   
GF(2^8):
  characteristic: 2
  degree: 8
  order: 256
  irreducible_poly: x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1
  is_primitive_poly: True
  primitive_element: x

In [5]: A = GF.Identity(4) * GF(10); A                                                                                                                                                         
Out[5]: 
GF([[10,  0,  0,  0],
    [ 0, 10,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0, 10,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0, 10]], order=2^8)

In [6]: A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A); A_inv                                                                                                                                                        
Out[6]: 
GF([[221,   0,   0,   0],
    [  0, 221,   0,   0],
    [  0,   0, 221,   0],
    [  0,   0,   0, 221]], order=2^8)

In [7]: A @ A_inv                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[7]: 
GF([[1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]], order=2^8)
```